# How i run my program in maximum resolution screen? (python)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, resolution

I need to retrive resolution of my screen to apply my `Qt program` but `qt` such as the following code:

http://bashelton.com/2009/06/pyqt-center-on-screen/

Just work with the static resolution, I need to run my program with maximum size.

**Question:** How i run my program in maximum size of screen forever?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: GNU/Linux, Of course for final target , i should port to windows platform.

Comment: What do you do to start your program? Would it make sense to change resolution _before_ the main prog executes?

Comment: I need to a demo on GNU/Linux for now, (for my boss) such as full screen, no , not sense. Of course ,what differ?

Comment: Seeing the accepted answer, I realize I misunderstood your question - you are not trying to change the resolution of the screen, just the size of the window in which your program executes. Hence my questions will have made no sense. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `showMaximized()` on your application's `QMainWindow` to maximize the application. You can also call `showFullScreen()` on the `QMainWindow` should fullscreen the application, hiding most of the title bars and window dressings.